# Appium: dealing with android system interactions

Tags: appium, appium-android

I have a simple use-case. Within the android app, press a button and the browser app will open a URL.

The "Open With" dialog pop-up appears and allows you to select Browser or Chrome.

[image: Android Popup: Open with]

Which looks like this in the appium inspector:

```
<android.widget.ListView resource-id="android:id/resolver_list">
    <android.widget.LinearLayout>
        <android.widget.ImageView resource-id="android:id/icon">
        <android.widget.LinearLayout>
            <android.widget.TextView resource-id="android:id/text1">
    <android.widget.LinearLayout>
        <android.widget.ImageView resource-id="android:id/icon">
        <android.widget.LinearLayout>
            <android.widget.TextView resource-id="android:id/text1">
```

Attempting to automate this seems like it should be trivial, but is causing me trouble. I can get the text of both "Browser" and "Chrome" as discrete `AndroidElement`s, but I cannot seem to be able to actually press the actual options.

Am I allowed to actually interact with these things or is this impossible because it's part of the android system itself?

To help figure this out, here is the setup of my page object.

```
@AndroidFindBy(id = "android:id/resolver_list")
private AndroidElement listParentElement;

public List<OpenWithOption> getOptions() {
    /* ... */
    List<MobileElement> elements = listParentElement
            .findElementsById(SYS_ID_PREFIX + "text1"); // Here's where I can only get the text element itself but can't figure out how to get the elements above that.
    return elements.stream()
            .map(mobileElement -> new OpenWithOptionImpl(mobileElement.getText(), mobileElement))
            .collect(toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a rookie mistake. Selecting the browser enabled the choice of "Just Once" or "Always" in the bottom of the screen and I didn't notice. I thought that just pressing the browser you wanted would launch it.

[image]